# Centering a facebook like button that changes size with CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, facebook

I have a facebook like button on my page:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.mysite.com/" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450"></fb:like>
```

I want the element centered and in the center of the page at all times regardless of how big it is.
Since the like button changes size as there are more counts, its position changes.

Is there anyway in CSS/HTML to maintain an absolute center for an element that has a dynamic size.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it supposed to sit over everything else?

Comment: Meaning? z-index is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although its a bit hacky, you could do this in a javascript calculation.

```
<div style="height:100px; width:100px;" id="bar">
   <fb:like .... id="foo" />
</div>

//jquery loaded previously
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var left = $('#bar').width() / 2 - $('#foo').width();
   var top = $('#bar').height() / 2 - $('#foo').height();
   $('#foo').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'left': left, 'top' : top });
});
</script>
```

Or something along this nature ...

Comment: The problem is that the like button has an extended width even when there are no like counts...